# Incremental search of a dbgrid using an edit box

Tags: delphi, dbgrid, incremental-search

It has been awhile since I have done any programming in Delphi and I was looking around for some examples on how to incrementally search a dbgrid by typing a search term into a edit box and I found the following code which seems to do the trick for the most part, but it checks for the filter condition on every column in the grid and I would like to limit the filter condition so it only checks one column in the grid (Column 1 for instance), how would I do that using the code provided ?

```
procedure TForm1.Edit1Change(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FDTable1.Filtered := false;
  FDTable1.Filtered := Edit1.Text <> '';
end;

procedure TForm1.FDTable1FilterRecord(DataSet: TDataSet;
  var Accept: Boolean);
var
  i: integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to DataSet.FieldCount - 1 do begin
    Accept := Pos(UpperCase(Edit1.Text),
      UpperCase(DataSet.Fields[i].AsString)) = 1;
    if Accept then exit;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Remove the loop. Replace i with 0 (1?).

Comment: That seems to have worked. Much appreciated.